# TortoiseSVN "Show log" displays incorrect logs (from a different respository)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository called `myrepos`, and required a new repository based on the HEAD. So, I used the SVN `hotcopy` command to achieve this - `myrepos-R2`.

Now, I have made a number of changes to `myrepos-R2`, and in the past, have been able to view these comments via tortoiseSVN. All of a sudden however, I can't seem to see the comments. The log keeps displaying the comments from the master. Also, when I try to view the logs of a particular file that I modified in `myrepos-R2`, tortoise says it can't find it.

Any ideas what is going on? Is this a tortoise problem or SVN?

Answer (score 10):

You have several options to solve this:

1. disable the log cache (Settings->Log Caching->Enable log caching)
2. since both of your repositories have the same UUID, allow ambiguous UUIDs (Settings->Log Caching->Allow ambiguous UUIDs)
3. Change the repository UUID on your second repository (`svnadmin setuuid REPOS_PATH`). I'd go with this option since each repository should have its own UUID anyway.

Comment: Disabling the "Log Caching" solved another issue: Tortoise not showing anything except revisions numbers in "Show logs". Thanks a lot Stefan :)